# how does react router disable default behavior of a tag?

Tags: reactjs

Normally when you click '<a' tag it causes browser to navigate.

But if you use `<NavLink` or other components like it they are rendered as '<a' tags.

So why doesn't the browser navigate to the href of those a tags?

Is it because there is an event listener on a tag using prevent default or returning false?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon further investigation it seems that there is some event delegation going on. React adds event handler at higher level and event bubbles up it gets cancelled. Event handler name is `dispatchInteractiveEvent` and it's attached to document node.

I'd venture a guess that react-router integrates with react's event handling to and control history api.

Answer (score 0):

When it navigates

```
<a href="/home">
```

In this case, href value is url.
But in NavLink

```
  <a href="#home">
  <div id="home"></div>
```

In this case, href value is id of DOM element.

Comment: this isn't always the case, react-router uses `/home` format